# Serialize, Compress and Encrypt in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, serialization, stream, compression

I want to write a C# class that can serialize, compress and encrypt objects, in that order. I need the resulting file to

- Be created as fast as possible
- Take as little space as possible
- Be as unreadable as possible

I've been researching and coding for a while and this is what I have.

```
    private void SaveObject(string path, object obj)
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            string password = "123";
            UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);
            RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(cryptoStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                binaryFormatter.Serialize(gZipStream, obj);
            }
        }
    }

    private void LoadObject(string path, out object obj)
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            string password = "123"; 
            UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);
            RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(key, key), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(cryptoStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                obj = binaryFormatter.Deserialize(gZipStream);
            }
        }

    }
```

I'm an amateur programmer and I have little knowledge about serialization, streams and encryption. I was even surprised this worked without a problem. My question is: Does this code follow the best programming practice and achieve the goals sufficiently without wasting time or resources?

Note: This is a generic method that I will use in my programs to store data locally.

Comment: Unreadable with password inline in the code? If you are not interested to spent your time on reading/understanding security concerns solved by encryption you will get comparable results from just compression.

Comment: As I said in the question, I will use this just for storing local files.Thus, I don't know what kind of encryption I should use. Also, don't I have to store the password somewhere?

Comment: It absolutely does not matter what kind of encryption you use. Since you don't know (or at least did not explicitly specified in the post) what problem  you trying solve with encryption picking one not going to make your code/data any more secure. I.e. can *you* read Word's docx file and understand its content (note that it is publicly documented file format with no encryption whatsoever) ?

Comment: I see. Then let's say I'm trying to prevent other people from understanding or modifying the file. Would that be possible with encryption or if not, to what extent would it be helpful?

Comment: @TerryAnderson - "don't I have to store the password somewhere?" - Not if *you* provide it when you encrypt/decrypt a file. Compiled libraries can be decompiled, so having the password in the source code you basically just add one more little corner to go around, compared to leaving the files unencrypted.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at https://github.com/HansHinnekint/EncryptionLib. The InfoBlockConvertor code of https://github.com/HansHinnekint/EncryptionLib/blob/master/EncryptionLibrary/InfoBlockConvertor.cs can be used as sample.

Only the compression needs to be added later on. That should not be that difficult.

Comment: Please explain what your code does (or rather, why it solves the issue in the question) within the answer. Answers on SO need to be self contained.

Comment: Well, the code I shared, answers the requests 'I want to write a C# class that can serialize, compress and encrypt objects, in that order. I need the resulting file to -Be created as fast as possible -Take as little space as possible -Be as unreadable as possible'

I did some testing and Compressing (using GZipStream) the Encrypted string (with my AES Algorithm) makes it longer, so this does not make any sense.

I selected AES (of which RIjndael encryption is a subset) as this allowed me to share code between .net and newer UAP (WinRT) applications.